# CMAKE Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

I have been building `freerpd` client for Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04 but an error is popping up :

```
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
```

when I use CMake 2.8. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You are either missing the `cmake-data` package, have managed to delete some files it contains, or Eclipse is using a different cmake than comes in Ubuntu, or is messing with the default modules path environment of cmake.

Comment: eclipse is out of question as it is not involved in building, cmake-data is already there ,is there any possiblity that i can correct it with path environment ?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pkg-config cmake-data` help, in case any of their files were corrupted?

Answer (score 57):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Comment: i tried that but no use

Comment: Did you also try `sudo apt-get install cmake-data` like dobey suggested?

Comment: yes ,                                                                                                                                                      ananthu@ananthu-System-Product-Name:~/FreeRDP-masteropy$ sudo apt-get install cmake-data
[sudo] password for ananthu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cmake-data is already the newest version.
cmake-data set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 594 not upgraded.

Comment: but it is not solved then also

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this nuts problem while compiling opencv. The problem is that CMake is not finding the pkg-config executable.

Fix like this:

1)In ubuntu terminal,

```
which pkg-config
```

You will get "usr/bin/pkg-config" if it's installed

2) Add

```
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config")
```

to your Cmake file, or in your build directory, run "cmake-gui" to add it using the GUI. Now, Cmake will find the pkg-config.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/issues/74

SOLUTION that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pkg-config cmake-data
```

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 18.4.